# FSSM -> An optimized backend is available for this platform! FSSM -> gem install rb-inotify encryption key required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm trying to get an application working (Canvas, a Learning Management System).  It is a Rails program.  I'm running Debian Sid.  My district asked me to take a look at it, so I'm trying to get it to run.  After setting it up and restarting apache, my server serves up the following error:

```
FSSM -> An optimized backend is available for this platform! FSSM -> gem install rb-inotify encryption key required, see security.yml.example
```

Any idea what's going on?  I tried uninstalling all dependencies and then reinstalling.  No go.  I don't have a hell of a lot of (read any) real experience with Ruby so I have no idea what my next step might be.